# 2sxc: Change Page name and Url based on EntityId

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a page with the url mysite.com/Bio/eid/nnn which displays the Bio of a person with eid=nnn.  This works fine.

Now, what I would like is for this page to respond to requests such as:  mysite.com/Bio/Bob-Smith.

where eid=123 is the eid for Bob Smith, for example.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try look at the Blog App, I think it been implement there

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can filter on any field. The main issue will be ensuring that you have a url-safe field, so it's best to use the string-url field for that and auto-generate a key so `Bob Smith` becomes `bob-smith`.

Check out the blog-app as an example.